# Metropolis-Hasting algorithm Trace plot

Tags: montecarlo

For MH proposal (Theta*=Theta(s)+u*) where u*~U(0,delta) and U denotes uniform distribution but for all the values of delta the algorithm is not satisfactory. How to do trace plot for such kind of MH algorithm?